# Jmeter Error :MIME type may not contain reserved characters

Tags: jmeter, mime-types

I am getting error while reading from CSV file as : MIME type may not contain reserved characters, when i hardcode same value in Jmeter UI it works -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MIME type may not contain reserved characters
    at org.apache.http.util.Args.check(Args.java:36)
    at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create(ContentType.java:227)
    at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create(ContentType.java:239)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.setupHttpEntityEnclosingRequestData(HTTPHC4Impl.java:1469)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.handleMethod(HTTPHC4Impl.java:794)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:569)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Reading from csv
[image]

Jmeter UI (Reading from csv , gives above error)
[image]

Jmeter UI (hardcoding mime type works)
[image]

Comment: print your variable in Debug Sampler if it was loaded from CSV and show your CSV Data Set definition